# IEEE-Template: Algorithm over both columns

Tags: floats, two-column, algorithms, ieeetran

I'm currently working on a paper using the IEEEtran template. I do have a pseudocode I would like to put into this paper. In a former paper I saw that it is possible to put this algorithm in a box which is in a figure and fills up both columns of the paper. I want to do it the same way, however, I was not able to manage it.

Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are most likely referring to the use of the starred float variant:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{algorithm*}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\lipsum[1-15]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

The above MWE uses [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) and [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) that provides the algorithm pseudocode presentation. However, you can place the algorithm inside a `figure` environment as well. Not sure what the journal might restrict in terms of package usage.

Note that using "one column" floats in a "two column" document usually leads to undesired placement. For one, they will end up at the top by default (unless you use [`dblfloatfix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfloatfix)), and usually the page *after* they are inserted (making first-page presentation difficult). See [Wide figures in two-column documents](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-widefigs) on the TeX FAQ.

---

Here's a version that does not use `algorithm`, but instead restyles the `figure` floating environment to box its contents (thanks to [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\floatstyle{boxed} % Box...
\restylefloat{figure}% ...figure environment contents.
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{figure*}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-15]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text.

Comment: Great, thanks. But when I but this inside a \begin{figure} ...  then it won't work anymore?!?

Comment: @Chris: I've added a `float` restyling. Note that you have to use `\begin{figure*}` ... `\end{figure*}` and not just `\begin{figure}` ... `\end{figure}`.

Comment: When I use \begin{figure*} with options [h!] or [htb], it puts the image very far from its place in source, usually on the last page. When I try the option [H] it does not produce any output. Is there anyway to force Latex to typeset this single column image closer to its actual place?

Comment: can I make it self-customized? say make it as wide as 1.5 columns effectively Thanks!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: I see you've [asked a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132422/5764).