# How to set algorithm width to avoid overfull \hbox problem

Tags: algorithms, width, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I wrote the following latex text, but the log shows an error that overfull \hbox(10.0pt too wide) detected. I am sure that the algorithmic part exceed the width limit. Even if I type a few words, the overfull error still exists. What should I do to control the algorithmic part width. It indeed exceed width limitation although it looks good. I found a command \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{length} in algorithm2e documentation, which package should I import to enable this command?

[image]

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Optimization algorithm for problem (\ref{eq:loss})}    \label{alg:ans_extr}
\begin{algorithmic}\small
    \STATE \textbf{Input:} $\mathbb{Q}$, $\{\mathbb{T}^+_i\}_{i=1}^N$, $\{\mathbb{T}^-_i\}_{i=1}^N$, $\{\mathbb{Q}^s\}$, $\{\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{Q}^s}\}$, $\alpha$, $\lambda$, $\vec{z}_t$, $T$~=~maximal iteration count, and $\delta>0$.
         ....
    \STATE \textbf{Output:} $\vec{w}_i$, $\vec{v}_i$.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: The OP is already using `algorithmicx` package (or `algorithmic`, I can't tell because the question does not have a MWE), it is not allowed to in addition load `algorithm2e` package. Nevertheless, to adjust the width, refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132425/250119 .