# Listing spanning two columns with ieee template

Tags: listings, ieeetran

I'm writing an article with the `IEEEtran` template, which have two columns.

I'd like to have a listing with source code that spans the two columns of the article, like in the attached figure.

I'm using the following command: `\lstinputlisting[frame=single, caption={blablabla}, label={blablabla}]{listings/blablabla.java}`

Does anybody know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: by span you mean continuing in the second column from first or occupying the space that is pagewide instead of using only one column? It's much easier to work with an example if you include a short and compilable one

Comment: in an analogy with a figure, this is a code that spans two columns: \begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}

i'd like to have a listing that behaves like that.

sorry if a didn't put a code, but it's exactly what I want to discover.

Comment: You can at least put the listing code that you want to make it span instead of us making up random nonsense.

Comment: \lstinputlisting[frame=single, caption={blablabla}, label={blablabla}]{listings/blablabla.java}

Comment: Related: [IEEE-Template: Algorithm over both columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54967/5764)

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{listings,multicol}  % <--- multicol only required, if the multicols= option shall be used
\usepackage{filecontents}       % <--- only needed to provide example code
\usepackage{lipsum}             % <--- only needed to provide dummy text

\lstset{language=Java, basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize}

\begin{filecontents*}{stuff.java}
package awt;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Hello {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f=new Frame("Hello World example of awt application");
    Label label1=new Label("Hello World", Label.CENTER);
    f.add(label1);

    f.setSize(300,100);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}


\lipsum
\lstinputlisting[float=*t, caption={A wide listing float, single column}]{stuff.java}
\lstinputlisting[float=*, multicols=2, caption={A wide listing float, itself dobule-column}]{stuff.java}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: float=*t worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to use `float=*t` and also allow page breaks?

Answer (score 5):

Until now I didn't find a way to make a listing span two colums using the command that reads the code from a file (`\lstinputlisting`).

However, I managed how to do it by putting the code in the latex document, as follows:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float=*]
code goes here
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually this can be done using `\lstinputlisting`. Here is the example for a C file:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\lstinputlisting[language=C,float=*,basicstyle=\footnotesize]{filename.c}
```

Change the `language` and `basicstyle` according to your source file and document requirements.